# Return value of function on VB6

Tags: vba, vb6

I have a question regarding on returning the value of function in VB6.0..below is my code

```
Public Function tracePackageError(oPackage As DTS.Package) As String
Dim ErrorCode As Long
Dim ErrorSource As String
Dim ErrorDescription As String
Dim ErrorHelpFile As String
Dim ErrorHelpContext As Long
Dim ErrorIDofInterfaceWithError As String
Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To oPackage.Steps.Count
            If oPackage.Steps(i).ExecutionResult = DTSStepExecResult_Failure Then
               oPackage.Steps(i).GetExecutionErrorInfo ErrorCode, ErrorSource, ErrorDescription, _
               ErrorHelpFile, ErrorHelpContext, ErrorIDofInterfaceWithError                                                                                           
            End If
    Next i

End Function
```

how am i gonna return the value of my function? Please help :(

Comment: all you need is to add `tracePackageError = [returning value]` somewhere inside your function, possibly after `next i`

Comment: Thank for your reply sir  KazimierzJawor...I'm still new in programming..what value will I input here in [returning value] as you said.. :(

Comment: Ahh ok I get it thank you Sir  KazimierzJawor :)

Comment: still not working sorry :(

Comment: Read the documentation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264233.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work for you...

```
Public Function tracePackageError(oPackage As DTS.Package) As String
Dim ErrorCode As Long
Dim ErrorSource As String
Dim ErrorDescription As String
Dim ErrorHelpFile As String
Dim ErrorHelpContext As Long
Dim ErrorIDofInterfaceWithError As String
Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To oPackage.Steps.Count
            If oPackage.Steps(i).ExecutionResult = DTSStepExecResult_Failure Then
               oPackage.Steps(i).GetExecutionErrorInfo ErrorCode, ErrorSource, ErrorDescription, _
               ErrorHelpFile, ErrorHelpContext, ErrorIDofInterfaceWithError 
               tracePackageError = ErrorDescription                                                                      
            End If
    Next i

End Function
```

Try it out and let me know

Comment: Thank you sir Indago..When I'm trying to test my function I got this error : "object variable or with block variable not set"..This is my code

    Private Sub Command1_Click()
         If tracePackageError <> "" Then
         MsgBox "error occured:" & vbCrLf & tracePackageError
         End If
    End Sub

Comment: Im getting error here  For i = 1 To oPackage.Steps.Count